# Does templating help if the only priority is making it easier to change layout?

Tags: php, templates, model-view-controller

At the moment I have a website deployed using spaghetti coding - the PHP is intermingled through the HTML etc.

Each time there is a requirement to change anything significant with the layout, there is quite a big task to modify 100's of files to add / remove HTML, add/change classes and so on.

I started looking into templating and frameworks to try and make it easier as the theory is you separate presentation from logic which sounded ideal.

However upon further investigation I am struggling to see the benefit in this use case (I can see other benefits like cleaner code, easier for other developers to understand, possibility of designers being able to change layouts without involving developers and so on)

For example, today I have 200 files containing something like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <?php print $output; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

From what I have read, should I deploy templating I would end up with something like:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        {output}
    </div>
</div>
```

How does this make it any easier for me to change anything to do with the layout or presentation? I still have 200 files each containing HTML which need to be changed and instead of "PHP" I have placeholders.

However, if I want to add / remove a DIV or change a class, for example, I still need to do this manually in x files or use a search/replace etc.

Is there any easier way to achieve what I need to do?

Comment: Your first code block looks like a template to me already, only implemented in pure PHP. But why do you have "something like this" 200 times? Can't you re-use existing code? If, for example, you have that snippet 200 times with different classes, just make the class attribute a variable and you only need to have the snippet once. If you actually *need* to have 200 different code blocks, because of complex differences, then truly nothing can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually already using a kind of templating - doing this will not make your code easier to adjust.

The question is **why** do you need to change 200 files for a single layout change? Why don't you seperate this layout code (if it's the same) to a seperate file and include that file in your view so you'll only have to change 1 file when part of that layout changes? That's much more useful than just changing some syntax, which you clearly don't need here.

Comment: The actual code I am using will be more complex than this - for example, I have a header and footer file where I include all the wrap around layout like menus etc but on the actual page itself I might have static text, a form with anywhere from 2 to 20 fields of varying types or a datatable. If I change the class on the datatable for example then I need to search replace on every page with datatables and that is what I am trying to avoid

Comment: You can obviously seperate the header and footer and include that in every page. If there are parts of the form which are exactly the same multiple times, you can seperate that too. If these parts are also too different on every page, I don't think you can do much about it.